# I need a visual trigger when there is a response from a lead

Tags: apex, email

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Apex code, but I'm trying my best. Here is the situation I would like to resolve with a trigger: IF a lead sends a reply e-Mail, THEN display a message that says "new e-Mail" somewhere next to that lead file, so that our sales reps know they need to look at the lead. (See image below).

[image: Halp.JPEG]

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This cannot be resolved with a trigger.  Triggers are purely on the backend and can't do anything visually.  You can create an event on a trigger and assign it to your rep.  This might do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [inbound email service](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_email_services.htm&language=en_US) to do something like this.

Basically you would need to create an "Messaging.InboundEmailHandler" to look at the "From Address" on incoming emails and match it up to the lead email address.

You could then add a new field to the lead called "Last Email Replied Date" and update this from the handler.

Finally, you could write a formula that would evaluate true whenever the Last Email Received Date is newer than the LastViewedDate.

Comment: You could also hack something together using the last vieweddate just not sure if it will work in a formula lie lastvieweddate < lastemailreplydate

Comment: @eric I could definitely be wrong, but I'm not aware of a lastviewdate  or lastemailreplydate on the lead.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm

Comment: Oh I see lastviewdate now... not sure how I missed that! Still don't see the lastemailreplydate though.  Did you mean you could add that field and set it using an inbound handler?

Comment: No - Lastemailreply would be what the OP trigger would populate

Comment: Hi Eric and NS, thank you for replying to me. How would I go about making lastemailreplydate work? I actually think that would be an acceptable solution to this.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks again. I was able to accomplish this by creating a field called "attention required" and have it trigger "yes" any time a new e-mail came in. Appreciate everyone's help!